# How to add a class

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="post-content">
    <p>XYZ</p>
        <h4></h4>
    <p>XYZ</p>
        <h4></h4>
    <p>XYZ</p>
        <h4></h4>
    <p>XYZ</p>
        <h4></h4>
    <p>XYZ</p>
        <h4></h4>       
</div>
```

Now i want to add a class on the p which is just coming after p, want to hide it. Then after on h4 click want to show it.

Comment: And what bit of this is giving you problems? Or is this a "Please write my entire script for me" 'question'?

Comment: please add more detail. clear questions get clear answers.

Comment: +1, going to need to provide a bit more information before the question gets closed

Comment: Actually 1)i want to add a class on p tag which is just coming after h4 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, I would go with jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.post-content p').hide().next('h4').click(function(){ $(this).prev().show() });
});
</script>

<div class="post-content">
  <p>XYZ</p><h4>Click me</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#MyElement").addClass(classname);
$("#MyElement").removeClass([classname]);
$("#MyElement").toggleClass(classname);
```

to Add/Remove classes

[How to apply css class to an html element using jquery in ASP .NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315474/how-to-apply-css-class-to-an-html-element-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)